# Is a regression causal if there are no omitted variables?

Tags: regression, bias, causality

A regression of $y$ on $x$ need not be causal if there are omitted variables which influence both $x$ and $y$. But if not for omitted variables and measurement error, is a regression causal? That is, if every possible variable is included in the regression?

Comment: No, even if you included every variable in the world, it could be inverse causal. For example, a planet's proximity to its nearest star could be accurately predicted by the surface temperature of the planet, but clearly the causality goes the other way

Comment: @gazza89 - since that effectively answers the question, you might want to expand it into an answer.

Comment: What is "omitted variables"? Suppose I have one Y and 4 Xs in my dataset. I fit a model including all of 4 Xs. Then I have no omitted variables?

Answer (score 22):

No, it's not, I will show you some counterexamples.

The first is **reverse causation**. Consider the causal model is $Y \rightarrow X$, where $X$ and $Y$ are standard gaussian random variables. Then $E[Y|do(x)] = 0$, since $X$ does not cause $Y$, but $E[Y|x]$ will depend on $X$.

The second example is **controlling for colliders** (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/298750/39630)). Consider the causal model $X \rightarrow Z \leftarrow Y$, that is $X$ does not cause $Y$ and $Z$ is a common cause. But note that, if you run a regression including $Z$, the regression coefficient of $X$ will not be zero, because conditioning on the common cause will induce association between $Y$ and $X$ (you may want to see here as well [Path Analysis in the Presence of a Conditioned-Upon Collider](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353278/path-analysis-in-the-presence-of-a-conditioned-upon-collider)).

More generally, the regression of $Y$ on $X$ will be **causal if the variables included in the regression [satisfy the backdoor criterion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188557/omitted-variable-bias-solution/312138#312138)**.

Comment: Highly recommend the Book of Why, by Judea Pearl. Explains thoroughly what Carlos refers to.

Comment: What does $do(x)$ mean?

Comment: @naught101 it means you actually force X=x, in contrast to passively observing X=x, see here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211008/dox-operator-meaning/312130#312130

Comment: Thanks, but I am not clear on the notation. Does $X \rightarrow Z \leftarrow Y$ mean $Z$ causes $X$ and $Y$? Should the arrows be reversed?

Comment: @Esha It means both $x$ and $y$ causes $z$

Comment: This answer is also relevant, https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/306188/39630

Comment: @CarlosCinelli and Esha  after your clarification it seems that $Z$ in not a common cause for $Y$ and $X$ even if in the text is write this. It's correct?

Comment: @Carlos Cinelli. It seems me that the concept of bad controls as explained in Angrist and Pischke (2009) par 3.2.3 its enough to say something like "regression is causal if good controls are included". In other terms the controls are good if respect the backdoor criteria. What do you think about it?

Comment: @markowitz the description of bad controls in MHE is not enough for deciding which variables to adjust for. There are cases that do not match their description, for instance, see the first example here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59369/confounder-definition/298750#298750 .

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Carlos Cinelli's important answer to this question, there are a few more reasons that the regression coefficients might not be causal.

Firstly, **model misspecification** can cause the parameters to be non-causal. Just because you have all relevant variables in your model does not mean that you have adjusted for them in the correct way. As a very simple example, consider a variable $X$ that is distributed symmetrical around 0. Suppose that your outcome variable $Y$ is affected by $X$ in such a way that $E(Y\mid X)=X^2$. Regressing $Y$ on $X$ (as opposed to on $X^2$) will then will give an estimated coefficient for $X$ of about 0, clearly biased, despite you having adjusted for all (the only) variable that affects $Y$.

Secondly, and related to the topic of reverse causality, there's also the risk that you can have **selection bias**, i.e. that your sample has been selected in such a way that it is not representative for the population to which you wish to draw your inference. Furthermore, **missing data** can also introduce bias if the data is not missing completely at random.